# Getting warning ignoring option '--databases' due to invalid value 'testdatabase' in mysql while importing data

Tags: linux, mysql

i am getting warning  ignoring option '--databases' due to invalid value 'testdatabase' in mysql while importing sql data into a database.Its working fine when I do it on my local machine but same is not working on remote server through putty.I have copied the file on remote server.
heres my query

```
 mysqldump -u root -p testdatabase < /home/user1/mydump.sql
```

remote machine(linux) mysql version :  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.14

local machine(windows 7) mysql version : Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.21

Comment: The `mysqldump` command cannot be used to do imports. I would like to fix (edit) your question, but I cannot be sure whether you meant _exporting_ using `mysqldump > dump.sql` or if you actually did mean _importing_ (using something like `mysql < dump.sql`). Can you clarify, or make the edits yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its not getting reflected even though you tried @rups solution then there might be possibilty that database names are different across your machines. Check if database name in the host machine and remote machine is same.if no then make relevant changes to the database name and table name.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error message from `mysqldump`, except in my case the error was due to [MySQL bug #41209](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=41209).

If you have a `~/.my.cnf` that looks something like this

```ini
[client]
database = testdatabase

[mysqldump]
databases = false
```

And you ran `mysqldump > dump.sql`, you would get the error message

```
mysqldump: ignoring option '--databases' due to an invalid value 'testdatabase'
```

The error comes about because `mysqldump` reads *both* the `[client]` *and* `[mysqldump]` sections of the config file. Due to the way the MySQL CLI programs do option parsing, `mysqldump` assumes `database` (*i.e.* the `--database` option recognized by `mysql`) is short for `databases` (*i.e.* the `--databases` option recognized by `mysqldump`), hence the error. It is a long-standing bug.

Ordinarily, the [`--database` option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_database) for the client, `mysql`, specifies the name of the database to operate on, while the [`--databases` option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_databases) for `mysqldump` (note the `s` at the end) is a boolean switch that means

> consider all 'name' arguments as databases to dump, rather than inferring the database name as being the first non-option argument on the command line, and the remaining 'names' as tables.

How do you solve it?

1. Remove `database` from the `[client]` section of your `~/.my.cnf` and specify it as an argument to `mysql` instead
2. Alternatively, look into the [`--defaults-group-suffix` option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-file-options.html#option_general_defaults-group-suffix); make yourself a [shell alias](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html) if you feel like that option is too much to remember/type

Answer (score 1):

Mysql Restore use following command:

```
 mysql -u root -p testdatabase < /home/user1/mydump.sql
```